# How do I loop through directories(including hidden) in bash without 'find' command?

Tags: bash, shell, loops, scripting

My initial code was:

```
function recurse {
 for i in "$1"/*;do
    echo "$i"
    if [ -d "$i" ];then
      #echo $i
        count $i
        recurse "$i"
    fi
 done
}
```

But then I realised that this doesn't loop through hidden directories. What I am trying to do is make a script that will count all files and directories in a given directory(including hidden). My function to do this is:

```
function count {
  varname=($1/*)
  for varname2 in ${varname[@]}  # For each element
    do
        if [ -d $varname2 ] # Checks if directory
        then
                Directories=$(expr $Directories + 1)
        elif [ -f $varname2 ] # Checks if file
        then 
                Files=$(expr $Files + 1)
    fi
    done

  for a in $(ls -FA $1 | egrep '^[.].*[/]$') # Checks for hidden dirs
  do
   HiddenDirectories=$(expr $HiddenDirectories + 1)
  done

  for a in $(ls -FA $1 | egrep '^[.].*[^/]$') # Checks for hidden files
  do
   HiddenFiles=$(expr $HiddenFiles + 1)
  done
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's wrong with using the find command?

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? If `bash` 4, this becomes much easier with the `globstar` option: `for f in **/*; do` hits every file recursively under the current directory, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

With bash I suggest to use:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

---

From `man bash`:

> `dotglob`: If set, bash includes filenames beginning with a `.' in the results of pathname expansion.